# DOMPDF generating pdf very slow

Tags: php, html, pdf, dompdf

I am trying to generate PDF using a very simple HTML. However, it contains 5 images (less than 50KB in total).

It is generating PDF very slow. It's taking over 12 second to generate the PDF. I am running on Windows 10 (i5-4590) with XAMPP.

Below is my code:

```
<?php
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();

$html = <<<EOD
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        html {
            margin: 1%;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .header,
        .footer {
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            position: fixed;
            font-size: 26px;
        }
        .header {
            top: 0px;
        }
        .footer {
            bottom: 18px;
        }
        .center {
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        .divTable{
            display: table;
            width: 100px;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        .divTableRow {
            display: table-row;
        }
        .divTableHeading {
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        .divTableCell, .divTableHead {
            display: table-cell;
            padding: 0 33px;
        }
        .bottom .divTableCell {
            padding-top: 30px;
        }
        .divTableHeading {
            display: table-header-group;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .divTableFoot {
            display: table-footer-group;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .divTableBody {
            display: table-row-group;
        }
        div.img-border img {
            border-style: solid solid solid solid;
            border-width: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
            border-color: #eb0089;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="center">
            <div class="divTable top">
                <div class="divTableBody">
                    <div class="divTableRow">
                        <div class="divTableCell" style="padding-left:0px;"><div class="img-border"><img src="300-small.png"></div></div>
                        <div class="divTableCell"><div class="img-border"><img src="300-small.png"></div></div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" style="padding-right:0px;"><div class="img-border"><img src="300-small.png"></div></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="divTable bottom">
                <div class="divTableBody">
                    <div class="divTableRow">
                        <div class="divTableCell" style="padding-left:0px;"><div class="img-border"><img src="300-large.png"></div></div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" style="padding-right:0px;"><div class="img-border"><img src="300-large.png"></div></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            $customer_title - $customer_order_number
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
EOD;

$dompdf->set_option( 'dpi' , '300' );
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf", array("Attachment"=>0));
```

I am failing to understand on how to make it process faster.

Comment: What type of PNG images are these. I've seen in the past some PNG image types (e.g. grayscale) that have, for unknown reasons, required significant processing time. Also, the fact that you're using PNG means Dompdf will perform extra processing. If you switch to JPG or remove the images does the processing time improve?

Comment: @BrianS I do not know why it was slow, and how it was fixed, but it's working fine now. I have tried with many images (png and jpg), with same result before. I did not change anything in terms of PDF generating code. But overall project's code was changed a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In the third DIV of the first table row you forgot a closing quote for the `class` attribute:

```
<div class="divTableCell style="padding-right:0px;">
```

should be

```
<div class="divTableCell" style="padding-right:0px;">
```

And the same error again in the second DIV of the second row.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated this. But that did not improve load time.

Answer (score 0):

I have also pdf download loading issue because of image.

Must convert image into base64 then put base64 string to img src attribute

Ex.`<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.$base64String.'" />`